# Insert into an STL queue using std::copy

Tags: c++, stl, copy, queue, insert-iterator

I'd like to use `std::copy` to insert elements into a queue like this:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back( 1 );
v.push_back( 2 );

queue<int> q;

copy( v.begin(), v.end(), insert_iterator< queue<int> >( q, q.front() ) );
```

But this fails to compile, complaining that `begin` is not a member of `std::queue`.

Note: I tried it with `std::inserter` too - this also failed, this time saying that 'reference' is not a member of 'std::queue'.  `std::back_inserter` and `std::back_insert_iterator` also fail with the same error.

Am I missing something obvious, or do `insert_iterator`s just not work with queues?

Comment: Although the answers you've been given are good, personally I would just avoid std::queue and any other crippled container adapter.

Comment: Yes, sbi and Naveen's suggestion to use a deque would be a good alternative.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unfortunately `std::queue` 'adapts' the function known as `push_back` to just `push` which means that the standard `back_insert_iterator` doesn't work.

Probably the simplest way (albeit conceptually ugly) is to adapt the container adapter with a short lived container adapter adapter[sic] (eugh!) that lives as long as the back insert iterator.

```
template<class T>
class QueueAdapter
{
public:
    QueueAdapter(std::queue<T>& q) : _q(q) {}
    void push_back(const T& t) { _q.push(t); }

private:
    std::queue<T>& _q;
};
```

Used like this:

```
std::queue<int> qi;

QueueAdapter< std::queue<int> > qiqa( qi );

std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter( qiqa ) );
```

Comment: Genius.  Neat, beautiful, and exposes the odd decision to use the name push instead of push_back in the first place.

Comment: It's not `push_back`, because the point where the insertions happen don't matter conceptually. Besides, what would `push_back` mean for a `priority_queue`?

Comment: Conceptually it makes sense, I just used the work 'unfortunately' because it means that it closes off using the `back_insert_iterator` which could be really useful.

Comment: I agree with Kylotan's comment to the question. If you want to do things beyond what the queue ADT allows (basically pushing and popping), there's little point fighting the queue adaptor. - +1 to your elegant answer, though.

Answer (score 8):

Queue does not allow iteration through its elements.

From the [SGI STL Docs](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html):

> A queue is an adaptor that provides a
>   restricted subset of Container
>   functionality A queue is a "first in
>   first out" (FIFO) data structure. [1](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html)
>   That is, elements are added to the
>   back of the queue and may be removed
>   from the front; Q.front() is the
>   element that was added to the queue
>   least recently. Queue does not allow
>   iteration through its elements. [2]

You *can* make this work, but you *can't* use `insert_iterator`. You'll have to write something like `queue_inserter` that presents an iterator interface.

**Update** I couldn't help myself and deicded to try to implement the iterator you need. Here are the results:

```
template< typename T, typename U >
class queue_inserter {
    queue<T, U> &qu;  
public:
    queue_inserter(queue<T,U> &q) : qu(q) { }
    queue_inserter<T,U> operator ++ (int) { return *this; }
    queue_inserter<T,U> operator * () { return *this; }
    void operator = (const T &val) { qu.push(val); }
};

template< typename T, typename U >
queue_inserter<T,U> make_queue_inserter(queue<T,U> &q) {
    return queue_inserter<T,U>(q);
}
```

This works great for functions like this:

```
template<typename II, typename OI>
void mycopy(II b, II e, OI oi) {
    while (b != e) { *oi++ = *b++; }
}
```

But it doesn't work with the STL copy because the STL is stupid.

Comment: Andy isn't trying to iteratoe through the queue, but to append to it.

Comment: Yes, but I need an iterator-like thing to be able to push into it.

Comment: Otherwise your answer is reasonable, though. `:)` +1

Comment: @sbi, It's important that you understand "iterators" in C++ do a heck of a lot more than just "iterate". When they say it doesn't allow iteration, they're saying a lot more than "you can't enumerate the elements"

Comment: Why not implement the queue_inserter to correspond to the back_insert_iterator interface? `std::copy` isn't 'stupid' (IMHO!), it just requires an output iterator which isn't an onerous interface.

Comment: onerous? Seriously? My class perfectly implements OutputIterator. The fact that `copy` requires that I inherit `std::iterator` is just a leak in the abstraction. Does `char*` inherit from `std::iterator`?

Comment: Your queue_inserter isn't assignable, but apart from that you don't _have_ to derive from `iterator`, you only have to provide a specialization for `iterator_traits` if you want to able to use your iterator with standard algorithms.

Comment: `char*` does not inherit from `iterator`, but there is a specialization for `iterator_traits<T*>`. Inheriting from `iterator` is just the simplest way of getting `iterator_traits` to recognize your iterator. - May-be you'd realize the value if you tried to implement some algorithm that needs to know the `value_type` (C++0x's `auto` probably makes things a lot simpler in this department), or handle random access iterators and bidirectional iterators differently.

Comment: BTW, `std::copy` in particular commonly needs to know more about the iterators, so it can pick an optimal way to do it: e.g pointers + PODs can be memmoved.

Answer (score 3):

`std::queue` isn't a container in the STL sense, it's a container *adapter* with very limited functionality. For what you seem to need either `std::vector` or `std::deque` ("double-ended queue, which is a "real container"), seems the right choice.

Comment: Or use a for loop to push into the queue.  What I'm doing doesn't seem unreasonable, though, does it?

Comment: Not it isn't. See Frank's answer as to how to achieve what you want.

Comment: No it does not (functionally), but you will have to roll your own inserter unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it just won't work -- a queue provides `push`, but an insert iterator expects to use `push_front` or `push_back`. There's no real reason you couldn't write your own `push_insert_iterator` (or whatever name you prefer) but it is a bit of a pain...

Answer (score 3):

`insert_iterator` and `back_insert_iterator` only work on containers (or adaptors) with (respectively) `insert` and `push_back` methods - `queue` doesn't have these. You could write your own iterator modelled on these, something like this:

```
template <typename Container> 
class push_iterator : public iterator<output_iterator_tag,void,void,void,void>
{
public:
    explicit push_iterator(Container &c) : container(c) {}

    push_iterator &operator*() {return *this;}
    push_iterator &operator++() {return *this;}
    push_iterator &operator++(int) {return *this;}

    push_iterator &operator=(typename Container::const_reference value)
    {
         container.push(value);
         return *this;
    }
private:
    Container &container;
};
```

Unless such a thing already exists, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't.

Comment: I was just about to accept this answer, which looks excellent (although I haven't tried it) but Charles pipped you at the post.

Comment: It would be nice to have such an iterator in the Standard Library. However, regarding your implementation, I think it would be safer to have the dereferencing operator return a proxy object instead of the current object. Indeed, the code as it is allows you to do `push_iterator< queue< int > > it; it = 42;`, which is wrong (it also allows you to do `******it`, which is not more correct). The `operator*` should return an object defining the `operator=`.

Comment: You could also add to your answer the usual helper function allowing one to omit the container type: `template < typename Container > push_iterator< Container > pusher( Container & c ) { return push_iterator< Container >( c ); }`.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a `push_inserter` (i.e. an inserter that performs `push`es into the queue). As far as I know, there is no such iterator in the STL. What I usually do is sadly fall back to the good old for loop.

If you have the courage, you can roll your own iterator, something along these lines:

```
template <typename Container>
class push_insert_iterator
{
  public:
    typedef Container                      container_type;
    typedef typename Container::value_type value_type;

    explicit push_insert_iterator(container_type & c)
        : container(c)
    {}    // construct with container

    push_insert_iterator<container_type> & operator=(const value_type & v)
    {
        //push value into the queue
        container.push(v);
        return (*this);
    }

    push_insert_iterator<container_type> & operator*()
    {
        return (*this);
    }

    push_insert_iterator<container_type> & operator++()
    {
        // Do nothing
        return (*this);
    }

    push_insert_iterator<container_type> operator++(int)
    {
        // Do nothing
        return (*this);
    }

  protected:
    container_type & container;    // reference to container
};

template <typename Container>
inline push_insert_iterator<Container> push_inserter(Container & c)
{
    return push_insert_iterator<Container>(c);
}
```

This is just a draft but you got the idea. Works with any container (or, well, container adapters) with a `push` method (e.g. `queue`, `stack`).

Comment: It's called "back inserter" in the STL and you get one from `back_inserter`. However, this doesn't work on `std::queue`.

Comment: I know what a back_insert_iterator is: an iterator that performs push_back into a container. Queue does not have a push_back method, that is why back_insert_iterator doesn't work. The method for adding elements in a queue is push, hence the push_insert_iterator idea...

Comment: @sbi: Considering that "inserting" an element into a queue is made via the queue::push() function, `push_inserter` is not a bad name, IMHO

Comment: @Éric: No, it isn't. Not at all. However, my comment was written before Luc's answer ever had a `push_inserter`. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

`std::queue` is not one of the basic containers in STL. It is a container adaptor which is built using one of the basic STL containers ( in this case one of the sequential container either `std::vector`  `std::deque` or `std::list`). It is designed specifically for FIFO behaviour and does not provide random insertion at the given iterator which you want for the `insert_iterator` to work. Hence it will not be possible to use queue like this.

The easiest way I could think of to do this is to:

```
class PushFunctor
{
public:
    PushFunctor(std::queue<int>& q) : myQ(q)
    {
    }
    void operator()(int n)
    {
        myQ.push(n);
    }

private:
    std::queue<int>& myQ;
};
```

And use it like:

```
queue<int> q;
PushFunctor p(q);
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), p);
```

Answer (score 1):

for c++11

```
std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), [&q1](int data) {  q1.push(data); }  );
```

and c++14

```
std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), [&q1](auto data) {  q1.push(data); }  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case, you can write:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back( 1 );
v.push_back( 2 );

queue<int, vector<int> > q(v);
```

This will make a copy of the `vector` and use it as the underlying container of the `queue`.

Of course, this approach won't work if you need to enqueue things after the queue has been constructed.

Comment: Very good point.  Unfortunately my example was too simplified and that isn't what I want to do.

Comment: queue cannot use a vector. The container must support `pop_front`.

Comment: Argh! You're right. Due to templates, my test didn't show this. Well, I guess you can still create a queue that allows you to inspect `front()` and `back()`... :P