# The C++ STL function find() doesn't accept the iterator arguments of a user-defined class

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator

When I pass user-defined iterator arguments in std::find(), the GCC 5.2.1. compiler (on Ubuntu 15.10) gives two error messages:

(1)

> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:162:34: error: no matching 
>   function for call to ‘__iterator_category(Text_iterator&)’
>   std::__iterator_category(__first));

(2)

> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:204:5: error:  no
>   type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits’

The error is caused by the line `auto p = find(first, last, first_char);`, which is inside the find_txt() function. When the line is commented out, the code compiles seamlessly. Here's the code excerpt that causes the errors:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"//from B. Stroustrup's site

using Line = vector<char>;

class Text_iterator {

    list<Line>::iterator ln; //points to lines
    Line::iterator pos; //points to characters

    public: 
    Text_iterator(list<Line>::iterator ll, Line::iterator pp)
        :ln{ll}, pos{pp} { }
    char& operator*() { return *pos; }
    Text_iterator& operator++();
    bool operator==(const Text_iterator& other) const
        { return ln==other.ln && pos==other.pos; }
    bool operator!=(const Text_iterator& other) const
        { return !(*this==other); }
};

Text_iterator& Text_iterator::operator++()
{
    ++pos;
    if (pos==(*ln).end()) {
    ++ln;
    pos = (*ln).begin();
}
    return *this;
}

Text_iterator find_txt(Text_iterator first, Text_iterator last, const string& s)
{
    if (s.size()==0) return last;// can’t find an empty stringchar first_char = s[0];
    char first_char = s[0];
    while (true) {
        auto p = find(first, last, first_char); //<------------the PROBLEM!!!!!!
        //if (p==last || match(p,last,s)) return p;
        //first = ++p;// look at the next character
    }
}

void ex6()
{
    ;
}


int main()
{
    ex6();
}
```

I referred to the files mentioned in the error messages:

```
template<typename _Iterator, typename _Predicate>
    inline _Iterator
    __find_if(_Iterator __first, _Iterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
    {
        return __find_if(__first, __last, __pred,
        std::__iterator_category(__first)); //this is line #162 in stl_algo.h
    }
```

and

```
template<typename _Iter>
    inline typename iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category
    __iterator_category(const _Iter&)//this is line #204 in stl_iterator_base_types.h
    { return typename iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category(); }
```

Does the problem lie in `auto p = find(first, last, first_char);` or in those two GCC library files—that is, stl_algo.h and stl_iterator_base_types.h? What could be the possible ways to handle it?

I was preparing code for doing exercise 6, Chapter 20 of Stroustrup's *Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++*, 2nd Ed. and got stuck here. The search on the Internet for std::find() problems has been to no avail. None of the questions referred to the iterator arguments to this funtion.

Comment: TL;DR: Your `Text_iterator` won't be an iterator just because you name it that way. It doesn't fulfill the requirements placed on the iterator by the standard.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724009/why-doesnt-my-custom-iterator-work-with-the-stl-copy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard algorithms (including `std::find`) require that the used iterator meets the requirements of the [Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) concept. Among those requirements is

> `std::iterator_traits<It>` has member typedefs `value_type`, `difference_type`, `reference`, `pointer`, and `iterator_category`

According to the error message,

> no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits’

which probably refers to `std::iterator_traits<Text_iterator>`. So, apparently the custom iterator isn't an iterator since it doesn't meet the requirements.

Solution: Specialize `std::iterator_traits` template for the custom iterator type and define the required member types. Also make sure that other requirements of Iterator are met as well as InputIterator, since that is what `std::find` requires.

An example specialization:

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct iterator_traits<Text_iterator> {
        typedef ptrdiff_t          difference_type;
        typedef char               value_type;
        typedef char*              pointer;
        typedef char&              reference;
        typedef input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    };
}
```

Comment: An example of how to specialize `std::iterator_traits` would be useful too, since it's not intuitively obvious.

Comment: @MarkRansom added an example.

Comment: Another approach (preferred) is to add nessesary typedefs to iterator itself, if you have access to its code.

Comment: When I added the `typedef` inside the Text_iterator, I got this answer:

Comment: /tmp/cc5OjFBw.o: In function `Text_iterator std::__find_if<Text_iterator, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<char const> >(Text_iterator, Text_iterator, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<char const>, std::input_iterator_tag)':
twenty.cpp:(.text._ZSt9__find_ifI13Text_iteratorN9__gnu_cxx5__ops16_Iter_equals_valIKcEEET_S6_S6_T0_St18input_iterator_tag[_ZSt9__find_ifI13Text_iteratorN9__gnu_cxx5__ops16_Iter_equals_valIKcEEET_S6_S6_T0_St18input_iterator_tag]+0x78): undefined reference to `Text_iterator::operator++()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Jarisleif if you take a close look at your class definition, you'll find that you didn't define `Text_iterator::operator++()`. The linker is telling you this.

Comment: @user2079303 it was defined in my original file, I just didn't include it in the question code and forgot to add it back together with your tip. Now it compiles seamlessly.