# Defining a proxy-based OutputIterator in terms of boost::iterator_facade

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-iterators, proxy-object

I wrote this C++17 code and expected it to work out of the box.

```
class putc_iterator : public boost::iterator_facade<
    putc_iterator,
    void,
    std::output_iterator_tag
>
{
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    struct proxy {
        void operator= (char ch) { putc(ch, stdout); }
    };
    auto dereference() const { return proxy{}; }
    void increment() {}
    bool equal(const putc_iterator&) const { return false; }
};
```

I'm trying to match the behavior of all the standard OutputIterators by setting my iterator's member typedefs `value_type` and `reference` to `void` (since those types are meaningless for an iterator whose `operator*` doesn't return a reference).

[However, Boost complains:](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Xfz92sQzYRCOnXJO)

```
In file included from prog.cc:2:
/opt/wandbox/boost-1.63.0/clang-head/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:333:50: error: cannot form a reference to 'void'
        static result_type apply(Reference const & x)
                                                 ^
```

It looks like Boost is trying to hard-code the generated `operator*`'s signature as `reference operator*() const`. That is, `boost::iterator_facade` *could* deduce the proper return type of `operator*()` by simply passing along whatever was returned by `dereference()`; but for some reason it's just not playing along.

What's the solution? I can't pass `proxy` as a template parameter of the base class since `proxy` hasn't been defined yet. [I could pull `proxy` out into a detail namespace:](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xRxY4veiSocq0viI)

```
namespace detail {
    struct proxy {
        void operator= (char ch) { putc(ch, stdout); }
    };
}
class putc_iterator : public boost::iterator_facade<
    putc_iterator,
    void,
    std::output_iterator_tag,
    detail::proxy
>
{
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    auto dereference() const { return detail::proxy{}; }
    void increment() {}
    bool equal(const putc_iterator&) const { return false; }
};
```

but that seems awkward and is definitely something that "shouldn't be necessary."

Is this a bug in `iterator_facade`?  Is it a feature-not-a-bug?  If the latter, then how am I *supposed* to use it to create OutputIterators?

Also, a minor nitpick: even my workaround with the detail namespace is "wrong" in the sense that it makes `std::is_same_v<putc_iterator::reference, detail::proxy>` when what I *want* (for parity with the standard iterators) is `std::is_same_v<putc_iterator::reference, void>`.

Comment: `iterator_facade`'s documentation requires `c.dereference()` to return `F::reference`. Unsurprising, since it dates back to 2006. Nothing in the standard *requires* output iterators to define their `reference` to `void`; it merely permits it.

Comment: @T.C.: Sure. But does that mean that if I want that behavior, I have to not-use-`iterator_facade`, period? I'm posting in the hope that someone knows a clever answer, or says "oh hey we should fix that", or whatever.

Comment: I'm not very sympathetic, considering that an output-only iterator of this sort can be written from scratch in roughly the same number of lines. Also note that `iterator_facade` offers no way to customize `pointer`, either.

Answer (score 0):

Boost Iterator Facade was good at the time, but now it is outdated as it is not very flexible (it doesn't play well with `auto` and with r-value references that in principle can be creating by dereferencing a r-value iterator). I am not againts the facade concept, but it could be upgraded to C++11.

In addition now with C++11 is easier to write iterator from scratch.

Anyway, if you need to define a `reference` just to comply with the arguments to be passed, (and if you promise not use it) you can use `void*` instead of `void`. (Or perhaps for consistency use `proxy&` and define it outside the class).

```
class putc_iterator : public boost::iterator_facade<
    putc_iterator,
    void*,
    std::output_iterator_tag
>
{
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    struct proxy {
        void operator= (char ch) { putc(ch, stdout); }
    };
    auto dereference() const { return proxy{}; }
    void increment() {}
    bool equal(const putc_iterator&) const { return false; }
};
```