# copy vector into queue

Tags: c++, stl

I have vector

```
 std::vector<OrderInfo *> vec
```

and a queue

```
queue<OrderInfo *> *myQueue = new queue<OrderInfo *>;
```

I want to copy the vector into the queue. I tried using [How can I copy an entire vector into a queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168127/how-can-i-copy-an-entire-vector-into-a-queue]) this answer and also this [Insert into an STL queue using std::copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723515/insert-into-an-stl-queue-using-stdcopy])

but it's not working, how do I make it work?

this is what I tried:
myQueue = new queue(vec.begin(), vec.end()); 
i got

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘std::queue::queue(std::vector::iterator,
>   std::vector::iterator)’    myQueue = new
>   queue(vec.begin(), vec.end());

and when I tried this:

```
std::copy(vec.begin(),vec.end(),std::back_inserter(myQueue));
```

i got:

> required from
>   ‘BacStrategy::BacStrategy(EZXConnectionHandler&, const
>   string&, bool, const double&, int) [with Event_Type =
>   EZXOrderEventHandler; std::__cxx11::string =
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string]’
>   /home/yaodav/Desktop/git_repo/test/main.cpp:324:51:   required from
>   here /usr/local/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:490:7: error:
>   ‘std::queue*’ is not a class, struct, or union type
>          operator=(const typename _Container::value_type& __value)

Comment: Please show your code and explain how it is not warking. The Q&As you linked are the way to go, we cannot know what you did wrong without seeing your code. Read about [mcve]

Comment: you might have problems with your pointers. Maybe what you really need is a `std::vector<OrderInfo>` and a `queue<OrderInfo>` instead of a vector of pointers and a pointer to a queue, this will make things easier a bit

Comment: Why are there so many pointers? Why do you use `new` so much?

Comment: No. This is not the code that produces the error. In the code you pass `*vec.begin()` but the error complains about `vec.begin()`. Details do matter. Please do read this: [mcve]

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 it was a copy past error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myQueue` is a *pointer*, not a queue, and can’t be passed to `std::back_inserter`. To fix this, don’t declare it as a pointer.

Furthermore, `std::back_inserter` can’t be used with a `std::queue`, as the second link you posted explains.

Instead, simply write

```
std::queue<OrderInfo*> myQueue{
    std::deque<OrderInfo*>(vec.begin(), vec.end())
};
```

If you really need a pointer, adapt the code as follows:

```
std::queue<OrderInfo*>* myQueue = new std::queue<OrderInfo*>{
    std::deque<OrderInfo*>(vec.begin(), vec.end())
};
```

Lastly, if you need to fill an already initialised queue, proceed as follows: create a temporary queue using the above and assign it to your pointer:

```
*myQueue = std::queue<OrderInfo*>{std::deque<OrderInfo*>(vec.begin(), vec.end())};
```

If this looks too messy you can also create a temporary variable for that queue — but in that case you need to use `std::move` to ensure that the queue gets move-assigned, not expensively copied:

```
auto tmp = std::queue<OrderInfo*>{std::deque<OrderInfo*>(vec.begin(), vec.end())};
*myQueue = std::move(tmp);
```

In the same vein, consider carefully whether you want to store `OrderInfo`s rather than pointers to `OrderInfo`s.

Comment: and now Im :getting /usr/local/include/c++/7.4.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:492:13: error: ‘class std::queue<OrderInfo*>’ has no member named ‘push_back’
  container->push_back(__value);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~

Comment: @yaodav Yes, as is explained in the link you’ve posted. My bad. The updated code works now.

Comment: thank you very much but I need it to be a ptr because the queue is a data member and the vector comes later on. so il just do it in the old fashion way (loop)

Comment: @yaodav I’m not sure I understand this: data members don’t need to be pointers! That said, I’ll update my answer. No loops needed.

Comment: what I mean is - from what I know is that if I have a none ptr data member then its init in the constructor, then I cant use your method. but if I use ptr (and I'm not considering the other aspect of ptr vs value) I can create the queue when the vector coming

Comment: You don't need to name `std::deque<OrderInfo *>`, just [use more `{}`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f28cf0acaa104de)

Comment: @Caleth I’m not sure whether I like this. I think I’d rather be explicit in this case, especially since brace initialisers for containers usually invoke the collection initialiser (which accepts `std::initializer_list`), but we want to call a different constructor. Too easy to accidentally call the wrong constructor here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph so why not `std::queue<OrderInfo *>::containter_type(vec.begin(), vec.end())`? A `std::queue` isn't a container, it has one as a member.

Comment: @Caleth Because there’s obviously a balance to be struck between explicitness and conciseness, and I believe that my code strikes this balance. That said, I don’t hate this conceptually, it’s just too verbose (but that could be avoided with a typedef).